# Need help Creating a big array from small byte arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

i got the following code:

```
    byte[] myBytes = new byte[10 * 10000];
    for (long i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        byte[] a1 = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
        byte[] a2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(true);
        byte[] a3 = BitConverter.GetBytes(false);

        byte[] rv = new byte[10];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(a1, 0, rv, 0, a1.Length);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(a2, 0, rv, a1.Length, a2.Length);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(a3, 0, rv, a1.Length + a2.Length, a3.Length);
    }
```

everything works as it should. i was trying to convert this code so everything will be written into `myBytes` but then i realised, that i use a long and if its value will be higher then `int.MaxValue` casting will fail.
how could one solve this?

another question would be, since i dont want to create a very large bytearray in memory, how could i send it directry to my `.WriteBytes(path, myBytes);` function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the final destination for this is, as suggested, a file: then write to a file more directly, rather than buffering in memory:

```
using (var file = File.Create(path)) // or append file FileStream etc
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(file))
{
    for (long i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        writer.Write(i);
        writer.Write(true);
        writer.Write(false);
    }
}
```

Perhaps the ideal way of doing this *in your case* would be to pass a single `BinaryWriter` instance to each object in turn as you serialize them (don't open and close the file per-object).

Comment: is `BinaryWriter` the fastest way to write this?
in this example i have 10000 iterations, but in RL it might be 1 Billion, which can take some time.

Comment: @Demsntic that makes it *even more important* to not try buffering it it memory. Also: I would not expect BinaryWriter to have the overhead if all those extra gen-zero intermediate arrays. So: yes it'll be fast, and certainly faster than having to allocate a huge array in memory, then think for ages, then do a huge single IO operation.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just Write() the bytes out as you process them rather than converting to a massive buffer, or use a smaller buffer at least?

Comment: My write function support writing one object at a time, so if i try to `.WriteBytes(path, rv)` it will Overwrite in each run of the loop.